Strategies for making NPCs respond to player queries based on the NPC's knowledge or activity
I'm developing a finite state machine AI where some interaction with the NPC can be made through a popup window with some choices. The image below shows how it looks:


The player (on the right in this image) interacts with an NPC (let's say a citizen on the left here) to talk or deal.

The player can define a question based on verbs (e.g. "search"/"need" etc.) to be applied to an item (e.g. "weapon" etc). The  button is used to show / hide a list of options like a combo box. (You can ignore the verbs "Item2"/"Item3" — they weren't properly cleared from a previous interaction).

The exit button stops the interaction.

The send button validate the current verb/item choice. Based on this, the NPC can react.


I can predefine a basic answer with a few words for any NPC, but I would like to find algorithms or methods to select an answer modulated by the NPC's knowledge of the environment, or the NPC's activity, which the designer has defined for each NPC.
I'm not sure what methods can be applied to implement a feature like this, or even what I should search to find good leads.

Unfortunately there's not just one simple algorithm for this — it's multiple entire fields of research: knowledge representation and reasoning explores methods for encoding and querying facts and inferences from a world model. Natural language generation would be used to express the information or attitudes extracted by that process in a form that looks like dialogue. I think this topic is too large to answer satisfyingly here — can you break it into steps?

You may also want to research how parser-based interactive fiction games work. You may be able to use an existing system for this, or adapt components / ideas to your use case.

Valve's GDC presentation "AI-driven Dynamic Dialog through Fuzzy Pattern Matching. Empower Your Writers!" might also be a good point of reference. They standardize a way to do complex range queries on a set of facts to search for authored dialogue lines relevant to those facts.

Thanks DMGregory. I think the latest suggestion could be pertinent for me. Technically I have started to build a 2D array of dword as database, each line being a character and each row being the other characters. The same for objects. The dword data represents what the character knows about the character/object, e.g. 0 means he knows nothing and bits are used like 0x01 = know it, 0x02 = knows where it is etc... The next step is to use this data to build a behavior or an answer.
